# Android Studio - App not installed onto phone, but runs

Tags: android, sdk, manifest, intentfilter

I use Android Studio to run my app on my phone and it runs fine. But the application itself is never installed...
There is no icon for it in the menu. I have to "run" any time I want to test my app. I am presented with no errors.

I believe there is an issue with my manifest. What am I doing wrong here?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jb854.eda.kent.ac.uk.edanews">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".EDANewsApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.eda.kent.ac.uk" android:pathPrefix="/school/"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.CommentsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ArticleActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.FullscreenImageActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen_image"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.FavouritesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favourites"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentActivity" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: my comment is wrong, sorry. @BradleyWilson thanks for pointing out.

Comment: have you dragged the apk onto your phone initially? like installed in without Android Studio? I can only assume it's just debugging onto your phone and @xwhyLikeThis there is a default icon always installed with every new application, this won't be the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add category `LAUNCHER` and action `MAIN` to your `MainActivity`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.eda.kent.ac.uk" android:pathPrefix="/school/"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks! It was a very confusing issue

Comment: You're welcome. I see you're new to StackOverflow. If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: this is not working in my case https://github.com/Redgram/redgram-for-reddit/blob/master/Redgram/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: For me it was not having `DEFAULT` and `BROWSABLE`, since I already had `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER`.

Answer (score 2):

I was having that same problem because android studio didn't put this dependence in build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the direct debug-apk file for installing manually. If you want to install manually by copying APK file in storage then

1. Delete auto-generated APK file located in `/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

   2. Click on `Menu > Build > Build APK(s)`. This generates debug APK for you.

[image]

I am using Android Studios 3.0 Beta 7. This is works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Worked on Android Studio 3.0 (stable).