# Android: Changing the default acitivity removes access to application

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm having an issue changing the default activity in my Android manifest

Initially, the `MainAcitivity` was the default activity but I would like it to change to the `LoginActivity`. When I do this however, the app disappears from the app drawer. The only way I can access the app information (uninstall, remove data etc) is via the application manager.

I've changed the tags on the `LoginActivity` entry in the manifest as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015410/android-studio-app-not-installed-onto-phone-but-runs) but the issue is still there.

Here is a snippet of my current manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".ui.MyFirebaseApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="COMPANY_app_notification_click_action" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

How would I get the application back to the app drawer?

Comment: remove this line <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> . I guess this is not required.

Comment: @Surace Sorry, that was an artifact of me trying different things. Removing this also produces the same result.